# What is the difference between 'hold the fort' and 'hold the forth'?

Tags: meaning, differences, american-english

This question was asked in a job interview!

Comment: The difference is no one ever says "hold the forth". Having said that, here is the most common reason questions are closed (unanswered) on this site: *Please **include the [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573) are off-topic.*

Comment: @Dan Bron why so?

Comment: Same reason no one says "litigious cornhusking" or "gibbous enamel" or anything else no one ever says: no one has a reason to.

Comment: Because it doesn't mean anything. I suppose you could imagine a scenario where the Firth of Forth was a strategic asset in a conflict and someone issued the order to 'hold the Forth', but that would be a very situation specific use. 'Hold the fort' is an idiomatic, metaphorical phrase with a known and accepted meaning, 'hold the forth' isn't. I shall stop now as I'm sure you have had enough of me 'holding forth' on this issue.

Comment: If this was asked in a job interview, assuming you were the interviewee, how did you answer?

Comment: @DanBron - "Have you picked a date for your party yet?"  "Not 100% settled, but hold the forth."

Comment: @Harshit - "Fort" and "forth" are two entirely different words, with different meanings.  Learn to use a dictionary.

Comment: @HotLicks That would be *fourth*, with a `u`.

Comment: @DanBron - Not the way I spell it. ;)

Comment: no that's 'forth' without 'u'!

Comment: @Harshit What are you not getting? No one says "hold the forth". Either you misheard or are misremembering or your interviewer made an error or was attempting some kind of joke. But the bigger problem is in general we expect people to check at least a dictionary before asking here, and, reflecting on that research, to provide *us*, in the body of their questions, what *they* understand the words or phrases to mean.

Comment: I think there is a significance between them.. either these are used as phrases.. I know the only meaning of 'hold the fort'.

Comment: @DanBron I am not questioning your skills in English but the interviewer asked especially by spelling the 'forth' word.

Comment: @Harshit if you believe that, go to google and find us some credible quotes by native speakers (which are not typos) using the phrase "hold the forth", and [edit] those quotes, with sources, into your question. Then we may be able to answer.

Comment: @Harshit You are implicitly questioning my skills in English by denying the fact that no one says "hold the forth". They may say "hold forth", as Max indicated in his answer, or "hold the fo`u`rth" as HotLicks indicated in his joke, but no one says "hold the forth". Full stop. If you think that's not true, then you need to find some quotes and [edit] them into your question, as I said previously.

Comment: The fact that somebody asks something during a job interview does not mean that question represents correct English. The question is equivalent to "what's the difference between _schedule a meeting_ and _schedule a meat_". The only answer is "one of them is not English".

Comment: Well, I'm sticking by my (insincerely held) view that the interviewer wanted a reply relating to James I https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mQUbhcU1OpcC&lpg=PT189&ots=gBIXy6-ESJ&dq=%22hold%20the%20forth%22&pg=PT189#v=onepage&q=%22hold%20the%20forth%22&f=false *'Stirling Castle will be yielded to them, and they will hold the Forth.'*

Comment: @Spagirl ooh the river Forth, in Scotland!  I hadn't thought of that.  It's unlikely that the interviewer meant that, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @MaxWilliams You can rely on me to big up any Scottish connection!

Comment: @Harshit If you regularly use the expression "hold the forth", maybe you could tell us what you think it means?

Comment: @DranBron ,MaxWilliams and Oerkelens I got the point and I came to a conclusion that 'Hold the Forth' is not an English Expression while 'hold the fort' is an English expression. I guess that should be the answer to this question. Thank you for all of your explanations and thanks to those persons who down voted the question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean "hold forth" or "holding forth", which are completely different expressions to "hold the fort".

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hold-forth

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hold+the+fort

Alternatively you might mean "hold the fourth" which means "reserve the fourth of the month", eg *"Ok, hold the fourth as Tompkins might be in the office then."*

EDIT: another possibility, courtesy of @spagirl in the comments on the question:  "forth" could be referring to the river Forth, in Scotland.  In this context, "hold the Forth" could mean *"Make sure the enemy (in a military battle) do not cross the river Forth"*.  Quite often in a battle, especially in the old pre-flight days, rivers formed crucial tactical/strategic borders.

I think it's unlikely that this was intended meaning, but it's the only possibility that matches the spelling, if we ignore the fact that Forth (a proper noun) should have been capitalized.

Comment: No, I mean the difference between 'hold the fort' and 'hold the forth' or is there any signification in between them?

Comment: "hold the forth" is not an english phrase, which could be the required difference I suppose.

Comment: Was this interview question presented to you verbally, ie spoken rather than written down?  If so then I suspect you simply misheard the interviewer.

Comment: the interview was a verbal interview but the interviewer spell out the word 'forth'!

Comment: Was the interviewer a native English speaker?

Comment: @Harshit All instances of the word "forth" in Max's answer here are spelled the same way your interviewer spelled the word to you: `f o r t h`, no `u`.

Comment: @Harshit there's a limited set of possibilities: 1) you misheard them, or misunderstood somehow, 2) they genuinely (and mistakenly) believe that "hold the forth" is an English expression or 3) It was a trick question, to which the answer is *"'Hold the forth' is not an English expression."*.  Those are the only options.

Comment: @MaxWilliams That or the interviewer mistakenly believes 4th is or can be spelled without a `u`.

Comment: @DanBron that's covered by option 2.  Once we (or Harshit) establish which option is correct we can go on to discover how we got there.

Comment: @DranBron ,MaxWilliams and Oerkelens I got the point and I came to a conclusion that 'Hold the Forth' is not an English Expression while 'hold the fort' is an English expression. I guess that should be the answer to this question. Thank you for all of your explanations and thanks to those persons who down voted the question :(